# When I include only the jQuery 1.4 Library, I get an exception, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, include

I keep getting this error all over the place where I only have jquery 1.3 or 1.4 included.

"setting a property that has only a getter"

and a long list of warnings in the Firefox Error Console.

What's going on? I can't find any information on this issue =/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modules.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Just some Warning snippets:

```
Warning: reference to undefined property a[++e] 
Source File: /js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js 
Line: 30 
Warning: reference to undefined property a[0] 
Source File: /js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js 
Line: 30 
Warning: function oa does not always return a value 
Source File: /js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js Line: 18, Column: 165 
Source Code: th;n<r;n++){j=d[n];a.currentTarget=j.elem;a.data=j.handleObj.data;a.handleObj=j.handleObj;if(j.handleObj.origHandler.apply(j.elem,e)===false){b=false;break}}return b}}function pa(a,b){return"live."+(a&&a!=="*"?a+".":"")+b.replace(/\./g,"`").replace(/ /g,
```

Comment: Please show the full HTML head section you are using.

Comment: amvx, you must be doing something irregular -- to my knowledge, nobody else using 1.4.2 receives these errors simply by loading the library. Could you reproduce it on jsbin.com?

Comment: What are some of the Firefox Console errors?

Comment: posted some of the warnings to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `"use strict";` statement anywhere? That causes ECMAScript5 browsers to parse JavaScript a little different and could cause this to be returned as an error.

You can remove this to fix the error, but that means you don't benefit from `use strict`. Note that `use strict` works in whatever scope it is executed in. So, if you want to load jQuery as non-strict, but have the rest of your code be strict, you can do this:

```
//load jQuery here

//create a scope
(function() {
     "use strict";
     // your code here
})();
```

Comment: Eh.... Freudian slip -- I meant -- Out of interest, what browsers support ES5's "use strict" thingy?

Comment: The DOCTYPE is Strict. So I dont see how scoping to use strict works.

Comment: This is a strict mode for JavaScript only. A strict doctype is only concerned with the HTML markup.

Comment: But this doesnt happen in my code, it happens in the jQuery library.

Comment: "ECMAScript5 browsers" - what browsers?

Comment: If you have "use strict"; in the global scope, it will affect jQuery.

Comment: I believe the latest versions of all major browsers currently support at least pieces of the ECMAScript 5 standard. IE8, FF3.6+, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: This is an interesting to know, but I wonder how helpful it is to my problem.

Comment: Are you using `"use strict";` in your code at all? If so, that might be the cause of your error and you can fix it by changing the scope. If not, then there is something else wrong. Or, are you saying that jQuery has "use strict"; and that's the cause of the error?

Comment: There are no browsers that support "use strict" (http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). Thus "use strict" cannot be the issue.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that support was still pending.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question has already been answered, I felt this was necessary.

OP probably has strict warnings turned on in his about:config in Firefox.

To change this just load up `about:config` in Firefox then scroll down to `javascript.options.strict` and then change this value to `"false"`.

Comment: Actually... javascript.options.strict;false -- it was already set to false